# Wifi working but ethernet connection is not working (Error: Destination net unreachable)

Tags: networking, ethernet, ping, wired

I had to install a virtual machine on Virtual box. Initially, both Ethernet as well as WiFi were working.

Somehow, I messed up the network configurations of virtual machine.

After that I was unable to access internet on my host machine on Ethernet but WiFi was still working. From some online tutorials, I learnt about *ping* command.

1) The output of `ping -c 3 www.google.com` from command line terminal through WiFi is:

```
PING www.google.com (216.239.34.117) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 216.239.34.117: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=46.7 ms
64 bytes from 216.239.34.117: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=51.9 ms
64 bytes from 216.239.34.117: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=48.3 ms

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 46.703/48.988/51.916/2.190 ms
```

2) The ping output from LAN connection is:

```
PING www.google.com (192.0.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unreachable
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Net Unreachable
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Net Unreachable

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2000ms
```

3) Output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` command :

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

3) Output of `ifconfig` command :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:c2:17:e3:c7:6d  
          inet addr:192.168.0.71  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6ec2:17ff:fee3:c76d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3663 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4123 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2398876 (2.3 MB)  TX bytes:696669 (696.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:15414 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15414 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1150874 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:1150874 (1.1 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:48:9a:b8:d8:bb  
          inet addr:192.168.0.25  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9248:9aff:feb8:d8bb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:154062 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:89908 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:108917728 (108.9 MB)  TX bytes:19010105 (19.0 MB)
```

I tried many methods mentioned online, e.g. `sudo service network-manager restart`, but the `Destination Net Unreachable` issue is still not resolved

Please suggest.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is off-topic here. It has reached its End of Life.

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 ESM, it's supported by Canonical through Ubuntu Advantage, so use that support as both ESM & EOL releases are off-topic here unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Yes you all are correct. But I guess this might be a general issue